# Is tf.constant_initializer value stored in graph like how constants are stored in tensorflow ? If not where is the constant value stored?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

In tensorflow, if we create a variable with initial value as a constant, then the constant value will be stored in tensorflow graph and therefore you can't have large constant values, as the limit for tensorflow graph proto is 2GB. 
see eg:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
shape=(3*(10**8))
my_large_array = np.random.random_integers(low=0,high=10,size=shape)
print("Size of array in Giga bytes ",my_large_array.nbytes*(10**-9))
b= tf.Variable(name="constant_var",initial_value=my_large_array)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()))
    print("Init done")
```

**Output**:

```
Size of array in Giga bytes  2.4000000000000004
....
ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.
```

But when a constant initializer with the same value is used as the initial value, no errors are raised. eg:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
shape=(3*(10**8))
my_large_array = np.random.random_integers(low=0,high=10,size=shape)
print("Size of array in Giga bytes ",my_large_array.nbytes*(10**-9))
A = tf.get_variable(name="initializer_var",initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=my_large_array),shape=shape)
# b= tf.Variable(name="constant_var",initial_value=my_large_array)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()))
    print("Init done")
    print(np.array_equal(sess.run(A),my_large_array))
```

**Output**

```
Size of array in Giga bytes  2.4000000000000004
None
Init done
True
```

Where is this constant numpy array saved in the second scenario if not in the graph? Wouldn't the variable have an initial state in this scenario?

Comment: It seems the first variable gets type `tf.int32` and the second one is `tf.float32`, but that shouldn't make a difference in the protobuf size, I think... You may try using explicit data types everywhere and see if anything changes (in `tf.Variable`, `tf.get_variable` and `tf.constant_initializer`).

Comment: correct. If you add third parameter to tf.Variable() call: dtype=tf.int32, then it works.

Comment: @Vlad-HC The idea was not to make tf.variable work. I would like to know why tf.get_variable() is working without raising an error.

Comment: The tf.get_variable() is working because it will use dtype float32. So the `my_large_array` variable in this case will take 1.12Gb. The tf.Variable(), on the other hand, will use dtype int64 and take 2.24Gb of memory.